# Can't access .NET control from AsyncFIleUpload.OnUploadCompleted code behind

Tags: .net, asyncfileupload

I am using an AJAX Toolkit AsyncFileUpload as follows...

```
        <p>
            <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Choose a webstock file to upload..." ID="uploadResult" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnImport" Text="Import Data to Website &raquo;" OnClick="importData" runat="server" Visible="false" />
        </p>
        <asp:AsyncFileUpload  ID="afuStockImport"  runat="server" 
                OnUploadedComplete="uploadComplete"               
                OnClientUploadError="uploadError" 
                OnClientUploadStarted="StartUpload" 
                OnClientUploadComplete="UploadComplete" 
                Width="400px" 
                UploaderStyle="modern"   
                UploadingBackColor="#b9b9b9" 
                CompleteBackColor="#00FF00"
                ErrorBackColor="#FF0000"
                ThrobberID="myThrobber" 
                ClientIDMode="AutoID"/>
        &nbsp;       
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="myThrobber" style="display:none;" >  
            <img align="absmiddle" alt="" src="adminimages/uploading.gif" />  
        </asp:Label>
```

I am trying to access the btnImport control to make it visible on success of upload, but accessing it from the uploadComplete procedure in the code behind does nothing....

```
        protected void uploadComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //upload file to web file system
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
            if (afuStockImport.HasFile)
            {
                string strPath = Server.MapPath("~/admin/stockfiles/") + Path.GetFileName(afuStockImport.PostedFile.FileName);
                afuStockImport.SaveAs(strPath);
                btnImport.Visible = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ulEx)
        {
            //Error message
        }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers,
Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you **can** access that button but your changes don't applied as the uploadComplete method executed asynchronously. 
in my opinion its better to hide the btnImport using style="display: none;", handle client-side OnClientUploadComplete  event of the AsyncFileUpload and show button after file was uploaded successfully.

Comment: OH...yeah!  Obvious now you mention it.  Do'h.  So I could use the JS that's updating the message or potentially use an async updatepanel.  Thanks for your help.